# Can't fetch photo from url javascript

Tags: node.js, download, fetch, blob

I need to download the photos via urls. I use fetch API. I tried with cors and no-cors.

I guess I don't understand something in 'http' in general (headers or something else).

Here is my code:

```
const options = {
   method: 'GET',
   mode: 'cors',
};

fetch('https://artlight.ru/upload/iblock/a47/ART-1013 size13.jpeg', options)
      .then((response: any) => {
         console.log(response);
         response.blob();
      })
      .then((blob: any) => {
         console.log(blob);
      })
```

Whatever I do I get the same response:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url:
      'https://artlight.ru/upload/iblock/a47/ART-1013%20size13.jpeg',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }


undefined
```

What should I do to get my blobs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found axios the very same moment posted here.
This works for me.

```
path = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../../files', 'check.jpeg');

   async download(url: string) {

      const response = await Axios({
         method: 'GET',
         url: url,
         responseType: 'stream'
      })

      response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(this.path));
   }
```